# Unable to locateOnScreen

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you know of the service Steam, they currently have a summer sale going on in which they have a game. I wanted to make a program that would automate the game.

Currently im using `PyAutoGUI` to move and click, but I've run into a problem. I should be able to use `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('file.png')` to get the coordinates of something on the screen. But it just returns `None`.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
width, height = pyautogui.size()

for x in range(1):
    # im = pyautogui.screenshot()
    # x, y= pyautogui.position()
    # print(im.getpixel((0, 0)))
    # pyautogui.click()
    a = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('small.PNG')
    print(a)
```

And here's the image that I'm using in `locateOnScreen`:

[image: the image I'm trying to locate]

Comment: From the [documentation](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html), `locateOnScreen` returns `None` if the image is not within the screen.

Comment: @Miket25 I do have the image up on screen, which is the weird part

Comment: assuming the black side of the image aren't needed in the id, try cropping them out.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust tolerance to your image matching. Try from lower number (e.g. 0.5) and keep adjusting to as high as possible.

Example:
 a = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('small.PNG',confidence=0.7)